# Refresh one variable every second

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to refresh two variables named profittext and sumtext which will be refreshed and echoed in the following places every few seconds. I know AJAX is needed to do this but how do i actually make it work ? The only way i found out was to refresh the content of the whole file. is there any way to refresh specific variables? Any answers will be greatly appreciated . Thank you very very much.

```
<table>
if($profitandloss<$zero) {
    $profitText = "<div style=\"color: red;\">$profitandloss</div>";
} elseif ($profitandloss>$zero) {
    $profitText = "<div style=\"color: green;\">$profitandloss</div>";
}
// for profit and loss counting

$sum+= $profitandloss;
//

echo "<tr><td>" . $row['trade_id'] .         
        "</td><td>" . $row['selection'] . 
        "</td><td>" . $row['date'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['type'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['size'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['bidprice'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['offerprice'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['stoploss'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['takeprofit'] .
        "</td><td>" . $profitText . 
        "</td><td><a href ='delete.php?id=".
        $row['trade_id']."'>X</a>
    </td></tr>";  

$profitandloss=0;

if($sum<$zero) {
    $sumText = "<div style=\"color: red;\">$sum</div>";
} elseif ($sum>$zero) {
    $sumText = "<div style=\"color: green;\">$sum</div>";
}
}
echo "</table><br>";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<table style="border:1px solid black;">
<tr>
<th style="border:1px solid black;">Profit/Loss</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border:1px solid black;"><?php echo $sumText ;?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: The answers below give you a good place to start. You can also go with a javascript library that wraps this functionality. Have a look at this to get familiar - http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the concept of how to structure such code when I first started too. Although it's not specific to your particular variables, here's a quick example for how to update a var through AJAX with jQuery/PHP.

*Prologue*: If this is something you're going to be doing often, you'll want to learn **jQuery**, rather than using normal javascript alone. There are lots of great, free, resources on how to learn jQuery. Alternatively, if you're not satisfied with the free tutorials online, [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449399029) is an excellent book. I'll write the example in jQuery.

*Design*: Okay, so the way it works is this:

- Set a timer in javascript to execute a particular function every X seconds (you DO NOT want to do it every second).
- That function makes an AJAX call (with jQuery) to a .PHP file on the server, sending it the data necessary so that the .PHP code knows what to send back.
- The .PHP code grabs the data required (e.g., with MySQL) encodes it in a JSON format, and exits.
- A promise on the AJAX call is fired and the data sent from PHP is received. Process it as you will.
- Repeat from step 2.

If you have any questions about what the code is doing, please ask.

**AJAX.PHP**

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$return_obj = array();
$request_obj = NULL;

// our AJAX call used "POST" as it's 'type', so we look in that
// variable.
if ( array_key_exists("func",$_POST) ) {

    if ( $_POST['func'] === "get_update" ) {

        if ( array_key_exists("which_var",$_POST) ) {

            $which_var = $_POST['which_var'];
            $which_var = $mysqli->real_escape_string($which_var); // should use prepared statements

            // we sent 'num_people_logged_in' as our value here, so we'll be looking for a column/field
            // with that value. this assumes that some other code, somewhere else,
            // is regularly updating the table. it also assumes that there will only
            // be a single row returned, which will hold the value.
            $query = "SELECT '$which_var' FROM site_stats ";
            if ( $result = $mysqli->query($query) ) {

                if ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                    $request_obj[$which_var] = $row[$which_var];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$return_obj['request'] = $request_obj;
echo json_encode($return_obj);
die();

?>
```

**MYCODE.JS**

```
// this actually sends the AJAX request to the server.
function getUpdate() {

    var jqXHR = $.ajax({        
        url : "ajax.php",
        data : {
            'func' : 'get_update',
            'which_var' : 'num_people_logged_in'
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'POST',
        timeout : 10000
    });

    // attach 'promises' to the jqXHR object, which represents
    // the AJAX call itself. 'promises' are, in this context,
    // just events.

    jqXHR.done(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {        

        // this executes if the AJAX call succeeded.
        // the variable 'data' holds what the server
        // sent us.
        if ( ( data ) && ( data.request ) ) {
            receiveUpdate(data.request);
        }
    });

    jqXHR.fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {

        // this executes if it failed
        console.log("Fail: " + textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
    });

    jqXHR.always(function(a,textStatus,c){                    

        // this executes either way, after .done or .fail
    });
}

// this is called from jqXHR.done, on success
function receiveUpdate(request_obj) {
    if ( request_obj.num_people_logged_in ) {
        updateDOM(request_obj.num_people_logged_in);
    }
}

function updateDOM(num_people_logged_in) {
    if ( num_people_logged_in ) {
        $("#mydiv > p.update").html("The updated value is: " + num_people_logged_in);
    }
}

var timeoutID = null;

// setup our timer, to periodically make an
// AJAX call
function init() {
    timeOutID = setInterval(function(){
        getUpdate();
    },5000);
}

// stop the timer
function cleanup() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>AJAX practice</title>

    <!-- <link href="mycss.css" rel='stylesheet'> if needed -->

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="mycode.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            init();

            $("#cleanup").on("click",function(){
                cleanup();
            });

        }); // end ready

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id='mydiv'>
        <p>
            How many people are online?
        </p>
        <p class='update'>
        </p>
    </div>

    <button id='cleanup'>Stop updating!</button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

```
setInterval(function(){
  //update your var here
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will needd two PHP pages:
- one with HTML and JS, which periodicly makes ajax calls and puts the result to the HTML
- second with json (or even plain text) output of your dynamic data piece

Unfortunately, writing the full code in the answer is not someting that people do at stackoverflow, so just look at small example below, and try to figure out the missing parts.

http://jsfiddle.net/AMEqz/

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function(r) {
   // your render logic HERE
   setTimeout(send, 1000);
}
function send() {
    xhr.open("GET", "/", true);
    xhr.send();
}
send();
```

p.s.: keep in mind that each ajax request will mean extra connection to your server, so make sure it can deal with the load ;)

Comment: the part that puts data to the html, so it becomes visible to user. (`b.innerText` in case of my fiddle)

Comment: i really have no idea how to do this... i would appreciate if you could help me